# Full-text content searching for Django-CMS

Tags: django-haystack, django-cms, whoosh

Probably the best way to integrate search with the Django-CMS is Haystack.

There is a [search_indexes.py snippet](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/searchdocs.html) at `django-cms` documentation. Does anybody managed to get this up and running?

I'm using whoosh as the search engine. Haystack works fine with my models, but this snippet for `cms.Page` model does not work. The behavior is not consistent. Usually I'm getting `No results found` message, but sometimes after running `manage.py rebuild_index`, or `update_index` I'm getting results for the same query string. The thing is, `rebuild_index` is not always helping. Could anybody help me to understand what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin for CMS called [aldryn-search](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-search).
It is currently did the trick for me. I use whoosh and haystack and it works.

My settings.py config for this is:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
        'PATH': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'whoosh_index'),
    },
}
HAYSTACK_ROUTERS = ['aldryn_search.router.LanguageRouter', ]
ALDRYN_SEARCH_REGISTER_APPHOOK = True
```

Answer (score 1):

There's https://github.com/piquadrat/django-cms-search which is lacking tests at the moment but will become the standard haystack tool for the django-cms.

Comment: the please open tickets on that repository explaining what exactly does not work and what you're trying.

Comment: django-cms-search was deprecated in favor of aldryn-search